# How do I include classes from log4j.xml when maven-shade-plugin minimizes the jar?

Tags: xml, maven, log4j, maven-shade-plugin

## What I Have

### `maven-shade-plugin` configuration in my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
    <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
    <shadedClassifierName>runnable</shadedClassifierName>
    <transformers>
      <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
        <mainClass>com.Main</mainClass>
      </transformer>
      <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
        <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
      </transformer>
      <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
        <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
      </transformer>
    </transformers>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals><goal>shade</goal></goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

### Log Appenders in my `log4j.xml`:

```xml
<appender name="ROLLING-LOG" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
  <param name="file" value="${logFileName}" />
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %p [%c] - %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
  <param name="target" value="System.out" />
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %p [%c] - %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

## My Problem

The `maven-shade-plugin` removes unused classes when building the uber jar, but it doesn't recognize `ConsoleAppender`, `DailyRollingFileAppender`, or `PatternLayout` as being used since they're only in the `log4j.xml`.

## A Solution

In the `maven-shade-plugin` configuration, I add a filter to force the inclusion of the entire log4j jar. This is a simple solution, but it ends up including more than I need.

```xml
<filter>
  <artifact>log4j:log4j</artifact>
  <includes>
    <include>**</include>
  </includes>
</filter>
```

## A Better Solution

In `Main.java`, I include these classes so that they're recognized as being used.

```java
static {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Class<?>[] classes = new Class<?>[]{
        org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender.class,
        org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.class,
        org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout.class
    }
}
```

## My Question

Is there a better way of doing this? (I was hoping there was an XML transformer or something that I could give my `log4j.xml`, and it'd be able to figure out what additional classes are used.)

Comment: is there any updates for this, or for log4j2?

Comment: Related to this, I am investigating a problem with `maven-shade-plugin`: my custom appender (added dynamically via code) doesn't work when using this plugin. So this plugin is doing something *shady*.